# Rails models: How to treat time constants correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, model, lambda

I know the following model code is not correct: as models get loaded only on server boot, time "constants" are loaded at that time only, too.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  def expiring?
    if (self.enddate - Time.now) <= 1.day
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

end
```

What do I have to correct how, so that the time values get evaluated **everytime "expiring?" is called**?

Thanks for your help!

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something I don't see anything wrong with the code you've given. Time.now will get evaluated every time expiring? is called. I'd probably shorten to:

```
def expiring?
  self.enddate >= 1.day.from_now
end
```

For a named scope you'd need to put it into a lambda so it does get evaluated every time (this sounds like the question you're actually asking):

```
named_scope :expiring, lambda { {:conditions => ["enddate >= ?", 1.day.from_now ] } }
```

Comment: Thanks! That answers everything!

Answer (score 2):

Models are loaded on server boot, but methods are called when they are called. If you're talking about `1.day`, then `1.day` isn't ever going to change (unless they change the number of seconds in a day) so you don't need to worry about that only being 'loaded' once.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!

I was only referring to: (self.enddate - Time.now).


So, if I'm not mistaken, this must be corrected only if we're talking about "named_scope"s **in** models...?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (self.enddate <= Date.today)
```

Could this be the solution ?